# How to render a DS fieldgroup programmatically in a node template?

Tags: 7, nodes, theming, display-suite, entities

I am overriding a Display Suite view mode of a node using the template suggestion *myLayout-node-myNode-full.tpl.php*.

I am getting the $node->content using the *node_build_content* function. Then I have access and I am rendering all the node display fields using:

```
drupal_render($node->content['field_myField'])
```

But I **cannot render fieldgroups** using the drupal_render function, as it requires array parameter, but my fieldgroups are **stdClass** objects that can be accessed as:

```
$node->content['#groups']['group_myGroup']
```

Printing the $node variable, I do not get any other reference to fieldgroups, eg. $node->content['group_myGroup'] does not exist.

Any suggestions on how I could render fieldgroups in my template file in Drupal 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`node_build_content`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_build_content/7) is probably not suitable for your use case. However you should use [`node_view`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_view/7) instead which calls `node_build_content` anyway but returns you the actual renderable array after it processes it and sends it through an alter as well.

For example:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  if (!empty($vars['node'])) {
    $node = $vars['node'];

    if ($node->type == 'my_content_type') {
      $vars['content'] = node_view($node); //optionally supply view_mode as a second argument
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can just `drupal_render($content)` from your node template.

Comment: This worked perfectly, now I have the $content variable with the actual renderable array which contains fieldgroup arrays too. Thank you.

Comment: UPDATE: Actually I already had the $content variable provided in my DS template file, without the need to use the node_view function.

Comment: I thought so, I was wondering why you were rendering the content manually. Thought you were doing something with DS arrays.